# Display Different Months For Members

Tags: java, display

I'm struggling with creating a method that when you enter a specific month (**from 1-12**), all the **Members** who have joined the **Society** class in that month with be displayed. For an example,

**I Enter: 3** (which indicates 'March')

**Output: 15** (Which indicates 15 members who have joined in the exact same month)

So far i only have a print output method which gives an error message if you enter anything below 1 or above 12 in my **(joinedInMonth)** method, **some advice or help would be much appreciated.**

Society Class:

```
public class Society
{
   private ArrayList<Member> myMembers;
   private Member member;
   private String societyName;
   public Society(String society)
   {
      myMembers = new ArrayList<Member>();
      this.societyName = society;
   }

   public String getSocietyName()
   {
     return societyName;  
   }

   public void join(Member member)
   {
      myMembers.add(member);
   }

   public void showMember(int listPosition)
   {
      Member member;
      if( listPosition < myMembers.size() )
      {
         member = myMembers.get(listPosition);
         System.out.println("Position " + listPosition  + ": " + member);
      }
   }

   public void joinedInMonth(int joined) {
        if (joined > 12 || joined < 1) {
            System.out.println("Invalid number");       
       }
   }

   public int numberOfMembers()
   {
      return myMembers.size();
   }

   public void printDetails()
   {
       for (Member m : myMembers) {
      System.out.println("Society Name: " + societyName);
      System.out.println(m.toString());
      System.out.println("--------------------------");
     } 

   }
```

Member Class:

```
public class Member
{
   private int month;
   private int year;
   private String name;
   private Society society;

   public Member(String name, int month, int year)
   {
      this.name  = name;
      this.month = month;
      this.year = year;
   }

   public int getYear()
   {
      return year;
   }

   public int getMonth()
   {
      return month;
   }

   public String getName()
   {
      return name;
   }

   public String toString()
   {
      return "Name: " + name + ", Month Joined: " + month + ", Year Joined:" + year;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could go over the members and check the month each one joined:

```
public void joinedInMonth(int joinedMonth) {
    if (joinedMonth > 12 || joinedMonth < 1) {
         System.out.println("Invalid number");       
    }

    long numJoined = members.stream().filter(m -> m.getMonth() == joinedMonth).count();
    System.out.printf("%d members joined on month %d%n", numJoined, joinedMonth);
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much, the code worked however since i would like to understand the code instead of being satisfied, how does the 'long' work as well as the stream and filter?

Comment: @MichaelWitherspoon Not sure I understand the question. Care to elaborate?

Comment: 1) stream() was called on your list which will convert it in to a flow of stream in which you can perform your intermediate operations.
2) filter() works on streams, actually filter takes a predicate which gives true/false on the basis of whether it is fullfilling the condition or not in your case those objects in list in which month value is actually equal to joined month so it will collect them only and igonre others.
3) count() this method will collect count of all objects in your list which are passing the predicate condition and are actually equal to joined month value.

Comment: You answered my question, i just wanted a quick code breakdown so i know roughly how the code works, thanks so much for the help. :)

Comment: @MichaelWitherspoon Gurinder S Panesar's comment above does a pretty good job of breaking the code down (thanks, BTW!). You could also read [Oracle's tutorials](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/ma14-java-se-8-streams-2177646.html) to get a better understanding